# How I can merge 2 XML strings into 1 in GOLANG

Tags: xml, go

I would like to merge 2 XML files into 1 new file.
first XML is schemaDtd and second XML is standard XML file with values ,
I want to merge them together into 1 new file.

my problem is that each XML start with "<?xml version='1.0' encoding..."
so I can't concatenate both files into 1 new file, (get wrong format on the second part that start with "<?xml version..")

so i try to merge them with this code , but i got error :

*this is my code*

```
var xml1 map[string]interface{}
var xml2 map[string]interface{}

err1 := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(DTDSchema), &xml1)
err2 := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlContent), &xml2)

maps.Merge(xml2, xml1)

fileContent , err := xml.Marshal(&xml1)
```

*- this is the errors :*

err1 : Error on unmarshal EOF ,

err2 : Error on unmarshal unknown type map[string]interface {},

Any idea ?

Comment: Without seeing XMLs question cannot be answered. Share also how you expect final XML.

Comment: I want a generic code without specific struct . Just need to remove the first line from second file 'xml version ...' on nice way

Comment: In general, you cannot simply concatenate two arbitrary XML documents into a new, valid document, because there are two root nodes to deal with. Potential solutions would need to specify how to resolve that issue (eg by choosing one and discarding the other or wrapping them both in a new root node, etc).

Comment: Everything will be much easier if you share 2 simple docs you are trying and expected results. Your errors suggest that something is wrong with input data. Merging XML and DTD also looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to take an XML file and give it an [in-line/internal DTD](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/winter15/cs144/reference/DTD.html).

You might find it easier to use a streaming/Sax-like parser to do what you want to do. That allows you to easily discard things you don't want (like processing instructions) as they're encountered.

- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nagygr/saxparser
- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mmcdole/goxpp#section-readme

Comment: Thanks , i checked it and I don't see any easy way to insert DTD into the XML parser .

Answer (score 0):

I leave here my solution for the next generations :-)

I found this package helpful:  https://github.com/beevik/etree

sample code:

```
    // read xml 
    doc := etree.NewDocument()
    doc.ReadFromString(xmlContent)
    root := doc.Root()
    if root == nil {
        msg := "Get wrong xml content: "+ xmlContent
        return errors.New(msg)
    }

    // read DTD 
    newXmldoc := etree.NewDocument()
    newXmldoc.ReadFromString(SchemaDTD)
    newXmldoc.SetRoot(root);
    newRoot := newXmldoc.Root();

// merge xml into DTD document 
    for _, e := range root.Child {
        newRoot.AddChild(e)
    }

    out, err := newXmldoc.WriteToString()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    // here out cotain both DTD + xml from 2 diffrent string
```